# Powershell || Cannot Change Cursor Shape

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Changing the Cursor Shape with the radio buttons in the powershell properties does nothing. Microsoft has hardly any documentation for editing the Powershell_profile.ps1, and **zero** references for commands that can be used to edit the Powershell terminal settings within the PowerShell_profile.ps1 file. All I have discovered how to do in this file is to change the window title of Powershell.

The default powershell cursor is horrible. How do I change it to where the changing the setting will **actually do something**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PSReadLine` module seems to be resetting the console properties every time when you change. Run `Remove-Module PSReadLine` to remove the module, console properties including cursor shape/size/colour would stay, but you will lose ReadLine features.

Comment: This works, but only if I add this line to Powershell_profile.ps1

Comment: Yep, because the module is always imported automatically everytime so you need to add into profile.

Comment: This still isn't changing the cursor in insert mode in vim, so my fight here isn't over. However, i got the cursor shape permanently changed in Powershell at least, so thanks anyway!